# Microsoft Access is null issue

Tags: ms-access

I have the SQL query below and i'm quite certain i'm approaching it incorrectly. What i would like to return every element that does not have the attribute type.Property that has the value "King"

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Object_ID, o.ea_guid as CLASSGUID, o.Object_Type as CLASSTYPE, o.name as Name, type.value as RoomType
FROM ((t_object as o
       INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as location
         ON o.Object_ID = location.Object_ID)
         INNER JOIN t_objectproperties as type 
         ON o.Object_ID = type.Object_ID)
WHERE location.Property = 'Location' 
  AND location.Value = 'Queens'
  AND type.Property = 'King' IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type.Property = 'King'` will always be true or false, never null,

so

```
AND type.Property <> 'King'
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I realized it after i posted the question. The problem i have is when i use it with the `iif` function i.e. IIF(type.Property <> 'RoomType', "None","Yes"). It returns me all attributes including RoomType

Comment: That can't be null either,  IIF(type.Property <> 'RoomType', "None","Yes") <> 'None', maybe. Always better to post your question, instead of a completely different one, by the way...